# How to create Xap file

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm new in WP development, and now stand before unbreakable wall:

Working in Visual Studio Express 2013

I created a simple journal app, all works fine in emulator and device. 
But when i was needed a xap file to upload it to windowphone store, and on top panel i choosed 
release-> any cpu , righ click on project name in solution explorer -> rebuilt solution ....
there is no xap file in the Bin directory, there is .exe and .pdb and others... but .xap is missing.

When i created a project, i choosed windows phone app -> empty app (windows phone)...

And just tested, if i'm creating a new silverlight app:  windows phone app -> empty app (windows phone silverlight) , xap file is saving without any problem.

So how to save my project, how to create a xap file from my xaml + c# project

Thank you very much!

Comment: restart VS and check again after build your solution..xap file should be there in your bin folder, You can search "xap" keyword though. It is created by its on in case of WP8 project. I have tested it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight Apps create .xap files, for Universal Apps (like the one you created) a .appx file will be created instead. Perhaps it is called .appxupload. Those packages reside in the subfolder AppPackages inside your project.

So if you take that file you will be fine. The store accepts those as well. The App will only support WP8.1 however.

If you need help in creating the .appx packages using Visual Studio 2013 you can refer to this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975357.aspx

Comment: oh, there is no such file there (  Here what release folder is contains:  App.xbf, AppxManifest, ***.build.appxrecipe, ***.exe, ***.pdb, ***.xr.xml, MainPage.xbf, Page1.xbf, Page2.xbf, Page3.xbf, resources.pri ( ***. - is project name)

Comment: If you right click on the project (in the Solution Explorer) there will be an entry "Store". Click on "Create App Packages" and follow through with the Wizzard.

Comment: I added a link to the MSDN documentation on package creation to the answer.

Comment: you are my savior! Now i got both  .appxupload and .appx